# Unable to get 2-d associative array in OUT param from JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql, procedure

I have created a procedure that accepts 5 IN param and 1 OUT param. Purpose of the procedure is to consolidate duplicate rows in one single row and return the list of consolidated rows. For this, i have used nested associative array. Inner associative array  stores column data indexed by integer value and outer associative array stores the row. When executed via SQL developer, it works fine and return the row. However, i need this proc to be called from jdbc code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TXN_CONSOLIDATION_PKG AS

  TYPE txn_info_array_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  TYPE final_txn_list_type IS TABLE OF txn_info_array_type INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  PROCEDURE TXN_CONSOLIDATION_PROC (tableName IN VARCHAR2, tableType IN VARCHAR2, startDate IN VARCHAR2, endDate IN VARCHAR2, 
    cardNumber IN VARCHAR2, rowCount IN INTEGER,final_txn_list IN OUT final_txn_list_type);

END TXN_CONSOLIDATION_PKG;
```

```
Java JDBC Call
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("url","username","pwd");
String proc = "{call TXN_CONSOLIDATION_PKG.TXN_CONSOLIDATION_PROC (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);}";
OracleCallableStatement s = (OracleCallableStatement)c.prepareCall(proc);
s.setString(1, "F");
s.setString(2, "D");
s.setString(3, "01/01/2019 00:00:00");
s.setString(4, "11/01/2019 00:00:00");
s.setString(5, "Joe");
s.setInt(6, 100);
s.registerIndexTableOutParameter(7, 100, OracleTypes.INTEGER, 40);
s.executeUpdate();
```

I am expecting to get the nested associative array back in output. But i am getting error as below :

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 83:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
>     null pragma raise return select update while with
>     
>      << continue close current delete fetch lock
>      insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
>      merge pipe purge
>   The symbol "exit" was substituted for ";" to continue.

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:204)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1041)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3665)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.executeUpdate(OracleCallableStatement.java:4739)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1352)
at com.fiserv.cwsi.ui.casetracker.util.CTUIUtil.main(CTUIUtil.java:2123)
```

### UPDATE 1:

Now i am getting a different error

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TXN_CONSOLIDATION_PROC'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 76:
PLS-00418: array bind type must match PL/SQL table row type
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below corrections will help :

```
create or replace package txn_consolidation_pkg as

  type txn_info_array_type is table of varchar2(100) index by pls_integer;

  procedure txn_consolidation_proc(tablename      in varchar2,
                                   tabletype      in varchar2,
                                   startdate      in varchar2,
                                   enddate        in date,
                                   cardnumber     in date,
                                   rowcount       in integer,
                                   final_txn_list in out txn_info_array_type);

end txn_consolidation_pkg;
```

Also you may have to modify the java call as below:

```
String proc = "{BEGIN TXN_CONSOLIDATION_PKG.TXN_CONSOLIDATION_PROC (?,?,?,?,?,?); END;}";
```

Comment: dont u think this will be just 1-d array, nothing tabular like a 2-d array

Comment: Yes that is right. Please only test with the change to procedure call.